# No fan speed regulation on HP Elitebook 1020 X360 G2

Tags: 20.04, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and am facing an issue with my laptop fan.
On startup the fan is blowing full speed and makes a lot of noise.

I installed `lm-sensors` and `psensor` and found out that one of the sensors is getting a temperature of 127°C which is irrelevant to me.

[image: Screenshot of psensor]

Any idea of what it can be ?

Comment: Typically a temp of 100 or over would cause a shut down. You have not said which sensor gives this reading.

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else.

Comment: @David It is in the Psensor screenshot

Comment: @ChanganAuto Just updated the UEFI version but no change unfortunately.
Still the same temperature on the sensor.
127°C is strangely a signed byte

Answer (score 0):

Notebook Fan Control doesn't seem to support your laptop but [it has profiles for similar HP laptops](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/tree/master/Configs).

Perhaps you're lucky with one of those. But beware like with anything involving temperatures, fan control and sensor probing; things come with no guarantees of any kind.

After probing sensors, I recommend to turn off your system and start it again. Don't leave your OS running for a long time if you've probed the sensors. Your Motherboard/OS may be left in an unstable/inconsistent state by the sensor probing.